How to align vertically by "\shortstack" in equation in LaTeX?
In equation, sometimes needs to add some mutiline text by \shortstack, which wouldn't be aligned vertically. For example
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \left.
    \begin{array}{r@{}l}
        hello1 & hello2 \\
        hello3 & hello4\\
        hello4&hello6\\
    \end{array}
    \right\}\shortstack{just\\a test}
\end{equation}
\end{document}


How move just a test down a little in this example?
